# hide/show Scrollview in Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone

I am using a Navigation Controller. On top of the AppDelegate window I added a view that contains a scrollview and toolbar that I want to be using throughout the app. They appear fine on all the view controllers that I am using in the navigation controller. Now I would like to be able to hide and show them from each view controller.
I can't figure out how that should work,
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly but if you just want to hide/show scrollbars in each viewcontroller just call:

```
myScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
myScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
```

in `init`, `viewDidLoad` or any custom method in your `UIViewController` subclasses.

Comment: What I want is to call the same scrollview into different xib files when I need it. The scrollview is set in Navigation Controller and is hidden when App is launched. How do I show it from any other xib file?

Comment: You can use this [NSNotification approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873450/calling-method-in-current-view-controller-from-app-delegate-in-ios/5873554#5873554)