# How can I know which ViewController is active?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsoperationqueue, concurrent-programming

I am downloading images using NSOperationQueue.

I want to call a method `reloadView` of my view controller once the image download is complete.

However when the download is in progress, it is fairly possible that user has moved to a different view. This other view will also have a `reloadView` method (e.g. first view shows total downloaded images count, and second shows thumbnails of download images)

Basically what I want is that whenever an image download is completed, I should be able to call the `reloadView` method of the active view controller whichever it is?

How can this be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't take that approach.  This is the kind of thing `NSNotificationCenter` is designed for.  When your image has finished downloading, post a notification.  In view controllers that need to know about it, listen for the notification in `viewDidAppear:` and stop listening in `viewDidDisappear:`.  Your downloading code doesn't need to know the details of your view controllers or their status.

Comment: Thanks Jim. That doesn't serve the purpose because I am saving the download images record in database, So the view will reload itself anyways from the database when `viewDidLoad` is called. What I want was is that as images are downloaded, if user is in first view: count should be updated or if user is in second view: thumbnails are added seamlessly.

Comment: this looks like my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873450/calling-method-in-current-view-controller-from-app-delegate-in-ios

Comment: Yes, I understood the problem.  I don't think you understood the solution I proposed.  Did you notice that the accepted answer for the question you link to uses `NSNotificationCenter` like I suggested?