# How would I know which ViewController is currently active

Tags: ios

I would like to know which ViewController is currently the active one. in other words, the one shown to the user?

Comment: If you need to know where you are in the view hierarchy, then you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please phrase your question a little bit more precise. from what i understand you want to do,
you could for example use notifications [(Tutorial to Notifications)](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/05/16/nsnotificationcenter-tutorial-using-the-notification-center-in-your-iphone-app/) and broadcast the name/type/object of your current viewcontroller to your application, whenever a new controller gets created & active.

please see this similar question which has good answer as well: [How can I know which ViewController is active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480867/how-can-i-know-which-viewcontroller-is-active)