# iOS UITableViewCell UIImageView setting on different conditions

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiapplicationdelegate

I have an app that has a `UITableView` and in my `Cells` I have `UIImageViews` and `UILabels` that change images/textColors for a day theme and a night theme (trying to be automatically set).

My issue is that I set the images and colors when the table is populated with `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and its during the day "theme", then if I reopen the app hours later in the night "theme" and the app is still in the "background" and not needing to be reloaded (ie `viewDidLoad` doesn't fire), the day "theme" shows until I scroll the `UITableView` and then the night "theme" shows when new cells are brought into view by scrolling.

How should I set the objects in my cells when changing around time of the day? I was thinking to use an `NSTimer`, but I'm not sure how to update the objects in my cells. I was also thinking about using the appropriate methods in the `AppDelagate` to set things in motion, but is there a way to force reloading the `TableView`?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could call `[tableView reloadData]` when `viewWillAppear` is called. viewDidLoad will not occur often enough for you, what you really want is to refresh when the view is about to appear to the user.

You can also check for `applicationWillEnterForeground` on your app delegate and signal to your view controller to reload its tableview this way as well.

Comment: I've added `[tableView reloadData]` to `viewWillAppear` and that does fire when I go back to that view controller from another view controller. So that solves that issue. However, I tried to also reload the data in `applicationWillEnterForeground` but I'm not doing it right. I tried `MyViewController *vc = (MyViewController *) vc; [vc.tableView reloadData]; and I don't think it actually reloads the data. How do I do this in `applicationWillEnterForeground`?

Comment: does a breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath get hit when you enter foreground?

Comment: No. It doesn't seem to fire if I hit Home and then go back to the app. I don't think I'm launching the `reloadData` method properly. How do I do this properly in the `applicationWillEnterForeground` method?

Comment: I did some searching this is what I needed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873450/calling-method-in-current-view-controller-from-app-delegate-in-ios
Thank you for the tip on `viewWillAppear`, as that solved another issue for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use applicationWillEnterForeground: and call reloadData on your table view.